# XML schema content model A for "any content except in namespace B"?

Tags: xml, xsd, wildcard, xsd-validation

Is there a way to restrict xsd:any such that only a specific namespace is excluded?

Something like this:

```
complexType name="A">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" namespace="##other"/>    
<!-- Somehow exclude all elements with names starting "B:" -->
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The XML complying to this type would be e.g.

```
<A>
<anything:whatever>
</anything:whatever>
</A>
```

But never:

```
<A>
<anything:whatever>
</anything:whatever>
<B:ad>INVALID</B:ad>
</A>
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this?

I'm only interested in XSD V1.0 validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can't be done in XSD 1.0.

XSD 1.1 added the `xs:any/@notNamespace` attribute to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Mr. Kay. I had this sinking feeling that this might be the case. The message "adopt V1.1" is coming over loud and clear.